# How to run the python webapp using flask & anaconda from vscode?

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code, pip, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda-Package, Flask, Pip & Vscode. I am currently running the development project on localhost using "**pipenv shell**" command then "**flask run**" command in vscode.

It works well on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ for simple webapp. But I want to display the prediction charts & tables on a webpage using pandas, numpy etc.

So, When I try to import

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

It displays this ->

```
flask.cli.NoAppException
flask.cli.NoAppException: While importing "app", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mdev\.virtualenvs\flask_md_project-itylmdvv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "D:\flask_md_project\app.py", line 4, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

[above error as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoeX0.png)

How do I use pandas,numpy,matplotlib etc from anaconda package along with flask through vscode for my python webapp ? Please help

Comment: How to use conda interpreter without using "pipenv shell" & "flask run" to run webapp on localhost ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the information you provided, the modules "pandas" and "numpy" are not installed in the Python environment you are currently using.

When we use the conda environment in VS Code, we use it as a [python environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment). Therefore, in this environment we need to install the module and then use this module. Usually, the module storage location of conda environment is (for example, base conda environment): "`\users\username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages`".

We can use the command "`pip show pandas`" in the VS Code terminal to check the installation location of the module:

[image]

For more information about flask in VS Code, you could refer to: [Flask Tutorial in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask).